# Global npm installs break after restarting terminal

Tags: linux, node.js, npm

I recently installed node using nvm and had no problems initially with installing globally packages with npm. But then I found that if  I close the terminal in which I originally installed the package, I will get "command not found" when attempting to use it.

For example, browser-sync. I closed the terminal after finding that it worked properly. When I opened it up later to continue working on the project I need it for, it turns out that now I get "command not found" in every directory despite installing it globally.

I am running Linux Mint Cinammon 17.3 with the latest version of node and npm.

Any help for this?

Comment: can you check what `which npm` command returns? it should return `/usr/local/bin/npm`

Answer (score 0):

I've since solved this problem by:

1. Completely uninstalling nvm and node.
2. Reinstalling node using apt-get
3. Changing npm config prefix to /usr/local
4. Correctly setting npm permissions

For some reason despite multiple uninstalls/reinstalls and playing with permissions before, it wouldn't work until I deleted all the folders created by node or npm before reinstallment. Weird.